# Do questions about Jenkins belong here or on Server Fault?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a question about Jenkins.
As follows:

> "In Jenkins when to use SSH site and when to use a node?

Am I supposed to post it here or on Server Fault?

Theoretically it seems like Server Fault is the more intuitive place, however, there are about 50 time more Jenkins questions on this site, and from a quick look most of them aren't directly coding related either.

Comment: I don't think SF would be a good choice. Did you consider [devops.se](https://devops.stackexchange.com/)? And that question by itself looks rather opinion based?

Comment: @rene, I looked at devop.stackexchange. It has few Jenkins questions and fewer answers still. I realize that theoretically it would be the best place, but it's also the place where I have the least chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Your question does not seem to have enough substance for any site on Stack Exchange to be honest because anyone answering the question has no idea about your environment and how it is set up. It seems opinion and implementation specific to your situation. The docs don't seem to list any objective reason to do one over the other but then again I am not familiar with Jenkins. I would recommend Stack Overflow as Server Fault is for professional administration issues. Additionally, their [help section](https://jenkins.io/participate/) points to Stack Overflow and others.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus. Thanks for the feedback. I was going to add more substance when I'll ask it, and I'll take your specific details to heart.

Comment: You're welcome. As long as you avoid soliciting opinions, drawn-out discussion, and provide a path for people to provide an objective answer then your question ***should*** be well received.

Comment: Additionally, I am not saying that you absolutely should not post at Server Fault but the bare question you presented will likely be ignored over there. If you need more guidance then make sure to check out their tours such as https://serverfault.com/tour

Comment: *but [devops.se] is also the place where I have the least chance of getting an answer.* ... funny enough the stats on [% answered](https://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) tell a slightly different story. DevOps and SF both have 78% of their questions answered where DevOps is slightly better.

Comment: @rene If I ask a question in devops.se and it goes unanswered, can I re-ask it here? Is it legitimate to move a question in such a situation?

Comment: The only thing that should matter is: On which site is it on-topic. If that returns multiple sites, then chose one and give the question a chance there. There is no SLA for getting an answer.

Comment: Just curious, which site did you decide to go with?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Was moved to different task. Will return to it later today. I want to do more due diligence on my question, but if I'll ask it (I probably will), I'll try in devops.se. Checked Jenkins question specifically, and it looks like my chances there are better than they are here as rene said.

Comment: Nice, good luck!

Comment: Posted. https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/in-jenkins-when-to-use-ssh-site-and-when-to-use-a-node

Comment: What do you mean by "SSH site"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pretty easy delineation

- Questions about using Jenkins to run unit tests, cover code, etc. are **on-topic** as we're using the programming tool aspects of Jenkins
- Questions about setting Jenkins up as a service, using Jenkins for deployment, etc. are **off-topic** as we need a server environment to run/deploy with.

If you need help setting up a server to run Jenkins, ask on [Server Fault](//serverfault.com). If you want to use Jenkins to deploy code to your server(s) you can ask on [Server Fault](//serverfault.com) or [DevOps.SE](https://devops.stackexchange.com) (since most systems use DevOps to do CI -> Deployment)

Comment: Couldn't you argue that Jenkins falls under the purview of [software tools commonly used by programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), though?

Comment: @EJoshuaS See my first bullet. Jenkins has things like running unit tests that are clearly within SO scope. But Jenkins can be run automatically on a server and trigger a code deployment to a live environment. That's way beyond SO scope. Better to ask experts in that area

Comment: Wouldn't those experts *also* be on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Makoto Not necessarily. While lots of people use Jenkins, they may not have set it up. That's why I try to get people to ask more niche questions on a SE site specifically focused on the topic you're asking about. You're far more likely to get an answer since they're not being drowned out by programming questions.

Comment: "using Jenkins for deployment" That is a bunch of nonsense. Developers *often* have to deal with that and have to write scripts or code to support it.

Comment: Also, [DevOps.SE] doesn't even have an [on-topic specification](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) yet. Hardly seems ready for recommending general usage.